# Wordpress: Fill a Custom Field with multiple values (array maybe)

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I need a Custom Field where I can fill it with multiple values, for example

Custom Field Value

Images = img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more precise on what you want to do? Are you manipulating the post meta data from the theme files?

If so, you can actually pass arrays to `update_post_meta` and it will automatically serialize it.

Comment: Well, I'm creating my own "theme", right now I'm getting the information from a webservice. And I have to store date like a custom post type. So I'm creating some custom fields.

I'm using this method: 

update_post_meta( $postId, 'Baths', $property['baths']); (for example)

And I would like to insert more values into a custom field, for example:

update_post_meta( $postId, 'Images', ("image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"));

Comment: Thanks dude, you pointed me in the right direction. But I think that I need to serialize the array by my own. Because I didn't get the result that I was expecting. (It didn't do it automatically)